# Output file wrong charset

Tags: c#, file, encoding, character-encoding

i want to copy all lines from text a that contain a certain text to file b with a small c# application.
It's already working, but the output file doesn't show special characters like "äöü". I already tried to set the charset to utf-8, but its not working.
Here's my function:

```
void BtnCnvClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if(File.Exists(txSource.Text)) {
                string[] srcFile = File.ReadAllLines(txSource.Text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(txOut.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                for(int i=0; i < srcFile.Length;i++) {
                    //progressBar1.Value = i/srcFile.Length;
                    if(i==0&&useHead) {
                        w.WriteLine(srcFile[i]);
                    } else {
                        if(srcFile[i].Contains(txFilter.Text)) {
                            w.WriteLine(srcFile[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                w.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Export successful!");
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Please input a valid file name and filter.");
    }
```

// Edit: It's working now, i just had to change it from UTF-8 to Encoding.Default!

Comment: try "Encoding.Default"

Comment: Oh, it's working - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(txOut.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

to this:

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(txOut.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```